# SQL Server select part of string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have table like this

```
Column1
-------------------------------------------------------
nn=APPLE IPod 44454,o=0006,o=TOP8,nn=USA,nn=TOP8+
nn=SAMSUNG G5 487894,o=04786,o=T418,nn=JPN,nn=TO478+
```

And I need update that table and get result like this

```
Column1                                                 Column2
---------------------------------------------------------------
nn=APPLE IPod 44454,o=0006,o=TOP8,nn=USA,nn=TOP8+        44454
nn=SAMSUNG G5 487894,o=04786,o=T418,nn=JPN,nn=TO478+    487894
```

My idea is but I can not fit with first character:

```
update tablename 
set [column2] = SUBSTRING(column1, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', column1) - 1 (column1, CHARINDEX(' ', column1) + 1, LEN(column1))
```

Comment: Without seeing example of other types of data (e.g. different products), I think your question might be too broad.  Also, SQL Server isn't the best place to be parsing such a complicated string.

Comment: A multi-valued field like what you describe is a HUGE red flag that screams "re-design me!".  Did you design this table, or was it given to you?  If it was given to you, then what is the specification for the field layout?  As @TimBiegeleisen said, we need additional sample records to even begin to make a suggestion for how to parse that string.

Comment: part infront of 4 character ',' from right side (only numbers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query can help you.

```
  UPDATE tablename SET [column2] =
    SUBSTRING((LEFT(column1,CHARINDEX(',',column1)-1)), CHARINDEX(' ', column1, CHARINDEX(' ',column1) +1 ) +1 ,LEN(column1))
```

Comment: This assumes that the product name always has two spaces in it, and this may not always be the case.

Comment: According to sample data, before the first comma only have 2 spaces.  For the performance aspect, I apply simplest and fast solution.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, given the second sample record, it looks like what you need is the last element of the space-delimited string in the first position of the comma-delimited string.  So write yourself (or find) a string-splitter function that accepts a string and a delimiter, and then your parsing logic is:

1. split the field at the commas
2. take the first element
3. split that element at the spaces
4. take the last element

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

The following answer is based only on the two records you actually showed us.  If we were to derive a rule from this, it might be that we want to extract the previous word (a product number) occurring immediately before the first comma in the string.  If so, then we can try the following logic:

- isolate the substring before the comma (e.g. `nn=APPLE Ipod 44454`)
- reverse that string (`45444 dopI ELPPA=nn`)
- then take the substring of that before the first space (`45444`)
- finally reverse this substring to yield the product number we want (`44454`)

Consider the following query, with data imported via a CTE:

```
WITH yourTable AS (
    SELECT 'nn=APPLE IPod 44454,o=0006,o=TOP8,nn=USA,nn=TOP8+' AS column1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'nn=SAMSUNG G5 487894,o=04786,o=T418,nn=JPN,nn=TO478+'
),
update_cte AS (
    SELECT
        column1,
        column2,
        REVERSE(
            SUBSTRING(REVERSE(SUBSTRING(column1, 1, CHARINDEX(',', column1)-1)),
            1,
            CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(SUBSTRING(column1, 1, CHARINDEX(',', column1)-1))) - 1)
        ) AS col2
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT column1, col2 FROM update_cte;
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

If you wanted to *update* your table to bring in these `column2` product IDs, then you can use the above CTE fairly easily:

```
UPDATE update_cte
SET column2 = col2;
```

Comment: Ok.How I can update my real table with 1000+ rows like this.

Comment: @Luka Are you asking me for a query, or are you raising a concern about performance, efficiency, etc.?

Comment: query. Thanks for that

Comment: UPDATE [dbo].[TABLENAME]
SET COLUMN2 = 

REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(SUBSTRING(COLUMN1, 1, CHARINDEX(',', COLUMN1)-1)),1,
CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(SUBSTRING(COLUMN1, 1, CHARINDEX(',', COLUMN1)-1))) - 1))